# Play a sound file when tapping table cell

Tags: ios, tableview, tablecell

What I'm trying to do when a user taps a cell I want it to play a sound. So far from what I have searched it has to be implemented in:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

}
```

I just don't know the best way to call it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a tableview delegate, you won't need to call it, you just need to set the delegate of UITableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a class variable for the audioPlayer:

```
AVAudioPlayer *cellTapSound;
```

in viewDidLoad (or viewWillAppear):

```
cellTapSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"cellTapSound" withExtension:@"mp3"] error:nil];

[cellTapSound prepareToPlay];
```

in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
// this line will rewind the player each time you tap again before it ends playing 
// you can tap as fast as you can and play some sort of a tune
// must have some fun while testing

if (cellTapSound.isPlaying) [cellTapSound setCurrentTime:0.0]; 

[cellTapSound play];
```

do not forget to:

- add [AVFoundation.framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html) to your project
- `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`
- Drag&Drop audio file into your project bundle and update the URL for AVAudioPlayer init
- read about [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067) to find out what else you can do with it

Comment: Absolutely perfect my friend.

Comment: Yah I knew at least enough to add that framework to my project, but thats good for other users who have the same question. Again thanks :)

Comment: Glad to be helpful! Cheers :)

Comment: Using the same method I just implemented this into my pull to refresh. Obviously changing the names and such. Much needed upvote!

Comment: While this still works perfect, I do notice lag until i tap my table cell a couple times, then no lag...ideas?